# Set file-specific expiration date on Google Cloud in Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

When storing a file in a GCP bucket, I know you can set rules on buckets, but is there a way to auto-delete that particular file from a bucket without life cycle rules after a certain number of days from Node.js? I'm wondering if it could be from the `options` object when calling `.bucket().upload()`, having trouble finding a full list of options. Or is there a way to set a rule on a bucket to only auto-delete files with certain properties / metadata?